# How do I build a basic Terminal from scratch

Tags: java, linux, macos, operating-system

I've looked online including on stackoverflow for some suggestions or pointers but anything I have found is overwhelming and I'm unsure where to start. Apologizes if I have overlooked something obvious.

I want to learn how a Terminal works and I would like to build one from scratch, I would love any advice or suggestions on material that covers the concepts and functionality required in a terminal but I don't just want links to source code. I have found plenty of open source projects but I find them overwhelming.

I would Ideally like to build my own terminal that can run on OS X, Linux and/or windows (I would probably use Java but would consider other languages) and eventually have a web interface ( would like to have my console in my browser ) I know this has been done but I want to do it myself so I can understand in detail how it works and Just to have a project to do.

What I'm really looking for is a starting point with reading material/tutorials to give me some direction. If it means taking a step back to something even more basic then a Terminal, I am happy to do that once I have something to actually program that will keep me progressing toward the main aim

Comment: This is way way too broad, SO isn't really a source for comprehensive walkthroughs or recommendations thereof. I suggest you take a look at the source of an existing terminal. (There are at least two in java: [JCTerm](http://www.jcraft.com/jcterm/), and [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/))

Comment: @millimoose surely there is basic concepts or functionality that would be required in any terminal? This is what I'm confused about

Comment: Look into virtual TTYs and ansi control codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind a terminal is an infinite loop which interprets and execute every command. Here is an example in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>) {
    system($_);
}

exit 0;
```

I know Perl isn't the most simple language to read (but surely it was the fastest to write), but this is all you need to understand the above program:

`<>` reads from standard input.

`system($_)` execute the command (where `$_` is a special Perl variable which works inside loops and represent the currently evaluated item, so, in our case, the given command).

You can try to run the above program saving it on your computer as `foo.pl`, open a terminal and execute `perl foo.pl`.

So, this is the basic idea. I think every language implements a command `system` which does the same (the name may change, but it's likely to be the same as well). You can have a look to `man system` to find out how this command works in `C`. I don't know Java, but I'm quite sure you have to search for something similar. From this starting point, I think you can start to build your own terminal.

Comment: That's a shell, not a terminal.

Comment: @millimoose, Yes, thank you to point out the difference. However, if I understand well, I can turn this shell to be a terminal adding another software which calls this one inside it, isn't it?

Comment: You can turn anything into anything by slapping on enough features. What I meant is, an OS shell is something that interprets commands thatc start and manage other processes. A typical GUI terminal emulator would be something that renders the output (text and control characters) of the shell in a window, and grabs keyboard events from the GUI toolkit and translates them to something the shell understands (stdin input and control characters again.) They're related pieces of software, which is why you can munge them together, but they perform entirely different tasks.

Comment: And what you described isn't "turning a shell into a terminal". It's "using a terminal to run your shell", meaning your answer to the OP's question of "how to develop a terminal?" is "use an existing terminal"

Answer (score 2):

Create a socket connection to the target computer, [read from it if any, display], [wait for user input, display, send that to the socket], repeat. You've got the basic terminal.

Comment: This question may have been too broad in 2013, but nowadays it has simpler answers.  One of them is a nodejs/npm ssh2+https+websocket+xtermjs, stack from back to front.  There is a lot of tweaking if you want to make it nice, but just get each part up then the next and you can have a working web terminal up pretty quick.  Be advised ssh's encryption is only from the webserver to the ssh server (local or remote).  Your connection over the web requires https and a valid cert.  You can obtain one free from Lets Encrypt.  If you can encrypt your websocket data as well, thats even better.